# typescript перегрузка возвращаемого значения функции

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы, перегрузка-функций

Нашел вот такой пример перегрузки функции

```
// сигнатуры перегрузки
type MakeDate = {
    (timestamp: number): Date;
    (m: number, d: number, y: number): Date;
};

// сигнатура реализации
const makeDate: MakeDate = (mOrTimestamp: number, d?: number, y?: number): Date => {
    if (d !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
        return new Date(y, mOrTimestamp, d);
    } else {
        return new Date(mOrTimestamp);
    }
};
```

Работает отлично, никаких проблем с ним нет. Но если пытаюсь изменить тип возвращаемого значения одной из перегрузок, то typescript выдает ошибку:

> Type 'number | Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.

```
// сигнатуры перегрузки
type MakeDate = {
    (timestamp: number): number;
    (m: number, d: number, y: number): Date;
};

// сигнатура реализации
const makeDate: MakeDate = (mOrTimestamp: number, d?: number, y?: number): Date | number => {
    if (d !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
        return new Date(y, mOrTimestamp, d);
    } else {
        return mOrTimestamp;
    }
};
```

Как правильно реализовать такую перегрузку?

Comment: Почему бы не писать функции по человечески, через `function`?

Comment: Нормального способа сделать перегрузки в стрелке нет, всё равно придётся кастовать. Для function есть механизм который позволяет удобно обходить типизацию в этом месте (хотя на самом деле он не лучше каста).

Comment: Правильно не делать такое странное

Comment: Так у вас даже пример переделаный из официальной документации https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Comment: @Alexey Ten этот пример я на хабре нашел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нужно такого хотеть.

Но если очень хочется что бы функция возвращала разные типы, то надо использовать [перегрузку функций](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads)

```typescript
function makeDate(timestamp: number): number;
function makeDate(m: number, d: number, y: number): Date;
function makeDate(mOrTimestamp: number, d?: number, y?: number): Date | number {
    if (d !== undefined && y !== undefined) {
        return new Date(y, mOrTimestamp, d);
    } else {
        return mOrTimestamp;
    }
};

let q = makeDate(1,2,3);
//  ^? Date
let z = makeDate(1);
//  ^? number
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmARVVMAUsymAzlKsgA4BciYIyARpgE4CUdDzbA3AFChIsBCgw48hZF0YtWAGkQATGTwWIAnqrmdEufAKHR4SNFn1SA8qwAqMEuUq16stoqUB+bW81eXa3QtEAB9-OUQAb35EGMQYYEQCJUQAQgBeNMRwJUxgGDBMZIAyIs1UjKywHLyCpXZI6Nim1kwoEFYkAoB3PUkCDUVkazsHCmp3dgEmgF9ETAAbUkwGpubW9tNh+zIxqinY6f5pgX551sQAR0RMswl8AgBGeQAmeQBmSf4Aei+YgD0PKdzgAva5icx9B6fH7-DxAA)

Но тут проблема в том, что внутри реализации вам придётся самостоятельно следить что функция возвращает правильный тип. Например в примере выше легко ошибится (что я и сделал сначала) и в `else` написать `return new Date(mOrTimestamp);` и TS вам об этом не скажет, а ошибку вы поймаете только при запуске.